# The table was not found. Reclassify Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, table, error-999999, reclassify

I am new to Python and trying to determine what is wrong with the following code:

-- error message --

> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>   The table was not found. [VAT_Recl_slope] No spatial reference exists.
>   Failed to execute (Reclassify).

-- code --

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.gp.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = my_workspace

arcpy.env.extent = "D:\\01_PhD_work_Alex\\ArcGIS\\01_Raw_data\\NZ_outline.shp"
arcpy.env.cellSize = "fault_dist_cp"

raster_list = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "*")
for raster in raster_list:
    print raster

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")

slope = "slope_2K"
distance_fault = "fault_di"
ditance_river = "river_di"
MMI = "kaik_grid_2K"
Recl_SPI = "spi_rcls2"

Recl_slope = arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(slope, "Value", "-100 5 1;5 10 2;10 15 3;15 20 4;20 25 5;25 30 6;30 35 7;35 40 8;40 45 9;45 50 10;50 100 11", "Recl_slope", "DATA")

Recl_fault = arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(distance_fault, "Value", "-100 5000 1;5000 10000 2;10000 20000 3;20000 30000 4;30000 40000 5;40000 50000 6; 50000 130000 7", "Recl_fault", "DATA")

Recl_river = arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(distance_river, "Value", "-100 500 1;500 1000 2;1000 1500 3;1500 2000 4;2000 2500 5;2500 70000 6", "Recl_river", "DATA")

Recl_MMI = arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(MMI, "Value", "-100 4 1; 4 5 2; 5 6 3;6 7 4;7 8 5;8 11 6", "Recl_MMI", "DATA")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's failing on the first Reclassify function - this is a general error that can point to a lot of causes, but the fact that it's telling you it cannot find the table and spatial reference doesn't exist probably means that the "slope_2k" layer lacks a proper spatial reference.  Check the Source tab in the Properties for this layer, and see if there is a coordinate system listed.  If not, that's your problem.

If the slope_2k layer looks fine, the most effective approach is probably closing out ArcMap entirely, re-opening, and then in a blank canvas load just the Slope_2k raster.  Then in the Python window, enter just the two lines:

```
slope = "slope_2K"
arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(slope, "Value", "-100 5 1;5 10 2;10 15 3;15 20 4;20 25 5;25 30 6;30 35 7;35 40 8;40 45 9;45 50 10;50 100 11", "Recl_slope", "DATA")
```

If that works, then the issue is resolved, and you can load in the rest and re-run the script.

Comment: I checked the data: Spatial data & coordinate system is OK. I tried with the data outside a geodatabase  and it is working ...Thank you for the help

Comment: No problem - glad it's working.